# ReactJS element not updating after setState being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, render, jsx

Good Afternoon, 
I have a React component that is dynamically rendered in reponse to an API call. I have set the value of one of the elements to a state within the component. During an onClick function (minusOne) this value is supposed to change. 
The value is initially rendered successfully based on the state, the function does indeed change the state, however the rendered element stays the same despite the state changing. Does anyone have any ideas of why this might be the case? 
If you have any questions, please ask away!

```
export class Cart extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        quantities: []
    };
    this.minusOne = this.minusOne.bind(this);
}

minusOne(i) {
    var self = this;
    return function() {
        let quantities = self.state.quantities;
        if (quantities[i] > 1) {
            quantities[i] --;
        }
        self.setState({
            quantities
        })
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    let cart = this.props.cartTotals;
    this.setState({
        cart
    });
    if(cart.lines) {
        let cartTotal = [];
        let quantities = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < cart.lines.length; i++) {
            if(cart.lines[i]) {
                quantities.push(cart.lines[i].quantity);
            }
        }

        //Initial setting of state
        this.setState({
            quantities
        })

        Promise.all(
            cart.lines.map(
                (cart, i) => axios.get('http://removed.net/article/' + cart.sku)
            )
        ).then(res => {
            const allCartItems = res.map((res, i) => {
                const data = res.data;
                return(
                    <div key={i} className="cart-item-container">
                        <img className ="cart-item-picture" src={data.image} name={data.name} />
                        <div className="cart-item-description">
                            <p>{data.name}</p>
                            <p>{data.price.amount} {data.price.currency}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="cart-item-quantity">
                            <button onClick={this.minusOne(i)} name="minus">-</button>



                            //This is the troublesome element
                            <p className="cart-current-quantity">{this.state.quantities[i]}</p>



                            <button name="plus">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            this.setState({
                allCartItems
            })
        })
    }
}
render() {
    return (
                    {this.state.allCartItems}
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading! Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Try moving your jsx to then render method , your code is unreadable like this

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. First, you need to render (including where the `onClick` is) in render(). `ConponentDidMount` is only called once and supposed to perform initialization but not render.
2. Then, there is a problem in `minusOne`:
   `quantities` points to `this.state.quantities`. So you are changing the old state, React looks at both the old state and the new one, sees there is no change, and dodesn't render, although the values have changed.

If you will copy this.state.quantities to a new array, like:

```
newQ = this.state.quantities.slice(0, -1);
```

Then modify newQ, then do

```
this.setState({ quantities: newQ  });
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

--- edited ---
I deleted everything I wrote before to make it more concise.

Your problem is that you assign what you want to render to a variable in `componentDidMount`. This function does only get called once, hence you asigne the variable allCartItems only once. The `setState` function does not have any effect because it does not trigger `componentDidMount` and therefore your variable allCartItems does not get reassigned.

What can you do? Well you can do a lot of stuff to enhance your code. First I will let you know about how you can solve your problem and then give you some further improvements

To solve the problem of your component not updating when you call `setState` you should move your jsx to the render Method. In the `componentDidMount` you just get all the data you need to render your component and once you have it you can set a flag for example like ready to true. Below you can see an example of how your code could look like.

```
import React from 'react';

class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      carts: null,
      ready: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('www.google.com').then((carts) => {
      this.setState({
        carts,
        ready: true,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const myCarts = <h2> Count {this.state.carts} </h2>;

    return (
      {
        this.state.ready
        ? myCarts
        : <h2> Loading... </h2>
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I made you a demo with a simple counter with some explanations of your case and how you can make it work. You can check it out [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lz15y5m2l). In the NotWorkingCounter you can see the same problem as in your component of the variable not being updated. In the WorkingCount you can see an example where I implemented what a I wrote above with waiting until your data has arrived and only then render it.

Some more suggestions concerning code:

Those two syntaxes below are identical. One is just a lot more concise.

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      carts: null,
      ready: false,
    };
  }
}

class Cart extends React.Component {
    state = {
      carts: null,
      ready: false,
    }
}
```

I would suggest to use arrow function if you want to bind your context. Below you can see your example simplified and an example on how you can achieve the same thing with less syntax.

```
export class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.minusOne = this.minusOne.bind(this);
  }

  minusOne(i) {
    ///
  }
}

export class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  minusOne = (i) => {
    /// minus one function
  }
}
```

Your minusOne could also be rewritten if you use arrow functions and be a lot smaller, something in the area of

```
  minusOne = (i) => (i) => {
    let quant = self.state.quantities[i];
    if(quant > 1) {
      this.setState({
        quantities: quant-1,
      })
    }
  }
```

In your `componentDidMount` you call `this.setState` twice. Every time you call this function your component gets rerender. So what happens in your component is when your mount your component it gets rendered the first time, once it is mounted `componentDidMount` gets called, in there you call `this.setState` again twice. This means your component get's rendered in the best case three times before the user sees your component. If you get multiple promises back this means your rerender your state even more. This can create a lot of load for your component to cope with. If you rerender every component three times or more you end up having some performance issues once your application grows. Try to not call `setState` in your componentDidUpdate more than once.
In your case your first call to `setState` is totally unnecessary and just creates load. You still have access to quantities in your promise. Just call setState once at the end of your promise.then() with both elements.

In the example below you are using the index i as a key. This is not a good case practice and react should also log you at least a warning in the console. You need to use a unique identifier which is not the index. If you use the index you can get sideeffects and weird rendering which is difficult to debut. Read more on it [here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

```
then(res => {
              const allCartItems = res.map((res, i) => {
                  const data = res.data;
                  return(
                      <div key={i} className="cart-item-container">
```

Another suggestion is to replace all `var` with `const` or `let`, as `var` exposes your variable to the global scope. If you don't understand what that means read [this](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75).

Last but not least have a look at [object deconstruction](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/). It can help you to clean up your code and make it more resistant to unwanted sideffects.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Ok I think I can see what you mean, I have checked out the demo you supplied and it does seem like the same issue. Where is this "CounterComponent" located as I am not seeing the solution to your demo? At the moment I am trying to refactor my code, however the componentWillReceiveProps function is not firing at any stage in the lifecycle.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope that will help you out for a bit. I also added a couple of tips on how you can improve your code style. Just comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to return a function at minusOne(i) method. Just update the state is enough. You should change the array by specific id.
       `let quantities = self.state.quantities;
        let mutatedQuantities = quantities.map((el, index) => {
             return (index === i) ? el - 1 : el;
        })
        this.setState({quantities: [...mutatedQuantities]})`

Comment: The reason I was returning that function is because it was being invoked on render. Gave your solution a try and it seems like I am having the same issue :(